# swift Export CAShapeLayer animation to gif

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, gif

I have a small code on Swift, that makes animation drawing of house. For animation drawing I use CAShapeLayer() based on UIBezierPath():

```
func setupDrawingLayer() {

    // Stop and remove all other actions and pics on the animationLayer
    clearLayer()

    if let _ = animationLayer{
        let pathRect: CGRect = animationLayer!.bounds.insetBy(dx: 100.0, dy: 100.0)
        let bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.minY)
        let topLeft = CGPoint(x: pathRect.minX, y: pathRect.minY + pathRect.height * 2.0 / 3.0)
        let bottomRight = CGPoint(x: pathRect.maxX, y: pathRect.minY)
        let topRight = CGPoint(x: pathRect.maxX, y: pathRect.minY + pathRect.height * 2.0 / 3.0)
        let roofTip = CGPoint(x: pathRect.midX, y: pathRect.maxY)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: bottomLeft)
        path.addLine(to: topLeft)
        ...
        path.addLine(to: bottomLeft)
        path.addLine(to: bottomRight)

        let pathShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pathShapeLayer.frame = animationLayer!.bounds
        pathShapeLayer.bounds = pathRect
        pathShapeLayer.isGeometryFlipped = true
        pathShapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        pathShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        pathShapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        pathShapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        pathShapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel
        animationLayer!.addSublayer(pathShapeLayer)
        pathLayer = pathShapeLayer
    }
}
```

I need to export this animation to GIF file. How can I do this? 
Or may be you know some other solution, that can animate UIBezierPath() drawing with exporting to GIF?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no off-the-shelf way to do this, and it would be tricky. You'd need to manipulate the time of the animation, and then use the presentation layer of the animation to capture frames to an off-screen context. Then you'd need to build a GIF out of the frames.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do this.

Comment: If you only need this one GIF, or a few (not as app feature), you can screen Capture video with Quicktime, open in Photoshop, crop, colour and compress to taste, and export as GIF.

Comment: Thank you.
But, I need to generate GIF, based on previously created animation.